# mysql json replace string to integer

Tags: mysql, json

How to replace all the value in JSON from string to integer?

```
+-----------------------------------+ 
| video_related                     |
+-----------------------------------+ 
| ["8626416", "8457156", "8605962"] |
+-----------------------------------+

Change to:
+-----------------------------------+ 
| video_related                     |
+-----------------------------------+ 
| [8626416, 8457156, 8605962]       |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: UPDATE video AS t1 INNER JOIN video AS t2 ON t1.video_id = t2.video_id SET t1.video_related = t2.video_related

Answer (score -2):

You can use **CONVERT** :

```
SELECT stuff
FROM table
WHERE conditions
ORDER BY CONVERT(name_column, SIGNED INTEGER);
```

Comment: That wouldn't work, because of the quotation marks

Answer (score -2):

You also can use CAST:

```
SELECT CAST(col AS SIGNED INTEGER)
FROM table
```